# Unable to load json data into tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary

i'm trying to do a weather application

```
 #import "LocationTableViewController.h"

@interface LocationTableViewController (){

    NSArray *hourlyData;
    NSArray *dailyData;
}


@end

@implementation LocationTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *str = @"https://api.forecast.io/forecast/cd8edc928426f2ac3e341441c7a9c6d3/37.8267,-122.423";
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

    NSDictionary *dataFromWeb = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

i took a json query that gives hourly and daily data, then converted it into dictionary. Here i created two dictionaries ie hourly dictionary and daily dictionary which contains fields like temperature, humidity, etc etc

My main goal is to create a weather app using both of the dictionaries hourly and daily by loading them into a table view.

```
    NSDictionary *hourlyDict = [dataFromWeb objectForKey:@"hourly"];
    hourlyData = [hourlyDict objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSDictionary *dailyDict = [dataFromWeb objectForKey:@"daily"];
    dailyData = [dailyDict objectForKey:@"data"];

   NSLog(@"%@", [[dailyData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"humidity"]);
}
```

By here i successfully created both the dictionaries and tried to NSlog the data it works fine.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I feel like my problem starts here in loading the dictionary into tableView.

1) In storyboard i embedded the table view into NavigationView.
2) i made the table View content as dynamic protocol
3) named the cell identifier as cell

i think problem starts here in sending data into table. Basically my app should contains 3 sections summary,hourly data and daily data. but i just want to try for now only on daily data.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}
```

Since i don't want any section, i removed this no.of. sections, but it threw me error, so kept it back and returned 0. , i also tried making it 1, but app crashes.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 NSLog(@"hello");
     return dailyData.count;
}
```

Here i want columns as no.of rows in dictionary, so i made dailyData.count.

Here starts the main problem, this - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:........ function is not being called, i tried to NSlog a message, it didn't show up

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"hello");

   cell.textLabel.text = [[dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"sunsetTime"];


    return cell;
}
```

can some one help me out please. Thanks in advance. Im new to programming.

here i attached the [Google Drive link for project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-F6rvUxTLswY3pIUmhuQTBHd0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should return 1 for number of sections, as you need at least 1 section in order to display some data...

Comment: i tried for it, the application crashes

Comment: What's the crash about?

Comment: Yeh i tried the same, it displays the dictionary it works fine when i call in viewdidLoad. but not woring for tableView

Comment: [__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facc8446810
2016-05-03 21:16:51.920 JsonTesting[1770:160452] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facc8446810' @Cristik

Comment: add [tableview reloaddata]; in viewdidload method in to the last line

Answer (score 1):

// sections should be 1 instead of 0

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return 1;
    }
```

`[dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` has following dictionary that cannot be assigned as Cell label text , you have to assign some string value to Cell Label text

```
   {
                apparentTemperatureMax = "60.49";
                apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1462316400;
                apparentTemperatureMin = "52.96";
                apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1462276800;
                cloudCover = "0.92";
                dewPoint = "50.37";
                humidity = "0.8100000000000001";
                icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
                moonPhase = "0.89";
                ozone = "351.23";
                precipIntensity = 0;
                precipIntensityMax = 0;
                precipProbability = 0;
                pressure = "1014.68";
                summary = "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.";
                sunriseTime = 1462281126;
                sunsetTime = 1462331002;
                temperatureMax = "60.49";
                temperatureMaxTime = 1462316400;
                temperatureMin = "52.96";
                temperatureMinTime = 1462276800;
                time = 1462258800;
                visibility = "8.779999999999999";
                windBearing = 275;
                windSpeed = "5.83";
            }
```

`cell.textLabel.text = [dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` you are assigning a dictionary to tableViewCell label. if you want specific key value then check below code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Number to Sting --> [Number stringValue]
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"sunsetTime"] stringValue];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Vinod convert float number to string . sunriseTime is a float so use this cell.textLabel.text =  [[[dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"sunsetTime"] stringValue];

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue you need to set your number of sections to 1 (you must always have at least 1 section for anything to display).

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

The reason you are getting a crash when you set your number of sections to 1 is because you are trying to use an NSDictionary as an NSString. You need to get an NSString from the NSDictionary. The below code will get the summary from the daily data for that row and display the summary.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *rowData = [dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"summary"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pass float into my table cell text, theres the mistake. We have to pass only text into that one, but i was trying to insert float values. now i passes some text values it works fine

Thank you all for your lovable support. Thank you once again

Comment: sorry bro we can pass anyvalue in to the tableview

Answer (score 0):

use this below code, And your code is working for me,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 NSLog(@"hello");
     return dailyData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"hello %@",[[dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"humidity"]);

   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dailyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"humidity"]];

    return cell;
}
```

And your output is given below,

[image]

humidity value is printed

hope its helpful

Answer (score -2):

You must show not to come out the data, because your `dailyData` is a  `NSArray!` How do you use an array as a string to use?Suggest you use a model, to store data.

```
    NSDictionary *hourlyDict = [dataFromWeb objectForKey:@"hourly"];
    hourlyData = [hourlyDict objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSDictionary *dailyDict = [dataFromWeb objectForKey:@"daily"];
    dailyData = [dailyDict objectForKey:@"data"];


    for (id  obj in hourlyData) {
        newsModel *model=[[newsModel alloc]init ];
        model.name=obj[@"summary"];
        [_dataArray addObject:model];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [[dailyData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"humidity"]);
```

In the table view delegate :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIde=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIde];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIde ];

    }
    newsModel *model=_dataArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=model.name;
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Daily array is already Array of dictionaries. Why there is a need of storing again in a model?